# Can we run ant file kept inside jar file?

Tags: java, ant, jar

Is it possible to run an ant file kept inside any jar from another java program ?

Ant build.xml file is kept inside masterjar.jar.

I am trying it like :

```
    pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ant compile",null, new File("/home/sys/masterjar.jar!/
"));
```

But i am getting error message :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant" (in directory "/home/sys/masterjar.jar!"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at Runner.TCRunner.main(TCRunner.java:100)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 3 more
```

If i try it by keeping build.xml file outside the jar, i am able to successfully run it.

Comment: I'am afraid this is not possible, unless you extract the `build.xml` from the jar then run ant against it. `Ant` expects that the build file is present on the filesystem see [running ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html). Witch sources dou you want to compile like that ?

Comment: As @A4L said above.. why? If you need to store it in the jar, you probably need to extract it to a temp location and then run it. But I would still come back to the question as to why you need this are there no other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant won't be able to pull that build file out. You should instead extract that from the jar (using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, perhaps?), [save it to a temporary file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), and then point Ant to that instead.